# Cassandra through Hector API Connection error

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have Cassandra 1.1.1 installed in my computer and i am trying to connect to it through Hector API. I am using the example from DeveloperStation.ORG. I have started the server also i have created the required keyspace and column family through cli. Now when i try to execute the program to insert data i get the following error.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured columnfamily authCollection)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:42)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl$1.execute(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:95)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl$1.execute(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:88)

Error encountered while inserting data!!
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:101)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:224)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl.operateWithFailover(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:129)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl.batchMutate(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:100)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl.batchMutate(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:106)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.doInKeyspace(MutatorImpl.java:219)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.doInKeyspace(MutatorImpl.java:216)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.KeyspaceOperationCallback.doInKeyspaceAndMeasure(KeyspaceOperationCallback.java:20)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecute(ExecutingKeyspace.java:85)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.execute(MutatorImpl.java:216)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.insert(MutatorImpl.java:55)
at com.examples.cassandra.CassandraExample.insertData(CassandraExample.java:31)
at com.examples.cassandra.CassandraExample.main(CassandraExample.java:131)

Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured columnfamily authCollection)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:16477)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:916)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:890)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl$1.execute(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:93)
... 14 more
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same error. Did you solve this?

Comment: sadly no. so studying other examples..

Answer (score 0):

"unconfigured columnfamily X" means you need to create columnfamily X before trying to insert into it.

Comment: He says he added the CF through the CLI!

Comment: i dropped the column family and again recreated it BEFORE executing the program still the same problem :(